# NullPointerException in Map class

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception

Long ago, I got the code from my ex colleague which worked for him but I can not make it work.

Using a debugger I concluded that my class has break  point at this method:

```
((Map<String, List<byte[]>>)metaData).put(HEADERELEMENTS, headerOMElements);
```

`put` method has declaration - `String key, List <byte[]> value`. I also tried with

```
((Map<String, List<byte]>>)metaData).put("HEADERELEMENTS",headerOMElements);
```

But it is the same situation. My `printStackTrace` returns `NullPointerException`.
I did the logging of `headerElements`

```
number of headerOMElements (headerOMElements.size();)=1
headers are(before calling the method PUT) (headerOMElements.toString();): [[B@d000d]
```

How to conclude what is the problem and to resolve it? I am not high level Java expert so I really need help.

Comment: is your metaData Map null?

Comment: problem is that some external class is defining that metaData and invoking the main method of this class. You mean to check it with isEmpty or size method?

Comment: when debugging examine metaData before the metaData.put(...)

Comment: ok. can I do it with metaData.toString? will it be readable? because I am sending that class on some server so it will take 20,30 minuites to test it. will it be readable enough with toString method or what is the best for debugging the metaData element?

Comment: Also metaData is defined on the method declaration level public byte[] invoke(Map<String, ?> metaData, byte[] data). what does this mean: "?> metaData"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the limited information you have provided, and assuming that it is accurate, the only possible way<sup>1</sup> that a `NullPointerException` can be thrown at that point is if `metaData` is `null`.

So ...

Modify your code to print out the value of `metaData` *immediately before* the statement where you believe that the NPE is being thrown; e.g.

```
System.err.println("metaData is " + metaData);
```

If the output shows that `metaData` is `null`, then the next step is to examine your code to figure out *why* it is `null`.  The chances are you've not initialized it, or you've passed it in from somewhere else and it was `null` there too.

If the output shows that `metaData` is NOT `null`, then one of the facts / assumptions you've stated in your question has to be incorrect.  For a further diagnosis, we would need:

- the *real* code, copied and pasted (not typed in like you appear to have done ... based on the typos), and
- the *complete* stack trace.

---

<sup>1 - For some kinds of `Map` you could also get an NPE if the key was `null`.  However, that exception would be thrown *within the `put()` method call*.  And besides, you say that you get the same problem when you use a literal String as a key.  So that cannot be the explanation.  The only other possible explanation is that there are multiple threads updating the map without synchronization.  That might given an NPE (randomly), but the NPE would be in `put` or some other method of the `Map` instance.</sup>

Comment: thank you Stephen...yes it returned me that metaData is null. But I am initiating it in some other class. Maybe some other class is also initiating it in behind because this is some IBM application with lots of default classes. Is there a way  I can somehow found out which class is initiating and also calling this my additional class? thank you

Comment: The only way you can find out is by reading the code, and tracing back through the calls to the place where that `null` starts its life.

Comment: metaData is declared in the method definition. So I suppose that from some place ( some other class which I pretend to find) this method is being called. What will be the method to trace back to find class which is invoking this method of this class? Some hint please, shortcut to return me to class which is invoking this one?(there are about 10000 classes in the system so it is hard to find) In mean while I marked your response as answered

Comment: public byte[] invoke(Map<String, ?> metaData, byte[] data) throws MXException

Comment: If you look at the stack trace, it should tell you what method called the `invoke` method, etcetera.

Comment: I wrote the declaration of the method in this class. can you help me what second paramtere means "?> metaData". I am not initiating it inthis class it is done somewhere else which I am try to find

Comment: how to create new instance of metadata? is this expression correct Map<String, Object> metaData = new HashMap<String, Object>();  because I am confused because of this expression:(Map<String, List<byte[]>>)metaData

Answer (score 1):

If the data, which you want to put into the map is not null, before you put it in, your map might be null and you get a NullPointerException.

OR 
the Exception is thrown anywhere else.

Comment: metaData is null. I can not find place where it is set. In this method it is just invoked and it is in the declarion of the method

Comment: hmm .. you could also create a new Map Object for the reference if it is null.

Comment: how to create new instance of metadata? is this expression correct Map<String, Object> metaData = new HashMap<String, Object>();  because I am confused because of this expression:(Map<String, List<byte[]>>)metaData

Comment: nearly, in the <> you use the same types as before.
new XXX<String, List<byte[]>();